# How to copy data from one sheet to another while skipping empty cells - Python and Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using python to format an Excel spreadsheet. I need to copy data from Column L in Sheet #1, "Main", and paste it into Column A in Sheet #2, "Data". I've gotten this working, but I also want to skip empty cells, which occur randomly in Sheet #1, and here I ran intro trouble.

I tried:

```
for i in range(2, 50):
    for j in range(12, 13):
        if cell.value != None:
            data.cell(row=i, column=j-11).value = main.cell(row=i, column=j).value
```

However I get the error message "NameError: name 'value' is not defined"

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure this is the answer but is cell defined before this loop? Should it actually be main.cell in the if statement? (i.e. if main.cell(i,j).value != None)?

Comment: That gets rid of the error message! But the blank cells are still showing up in Sheet #2. I think it's copying the data to the same numbered row instead of the next blank row. Hm...

Comment: Hi, Kate, I've never used Openpxl but I wonder if in your final line here, you actually want it to say: data.cell(row=i+1, column=j-11)...

Comment: Just got this to work:
for i in range(2, 50):
    for j in range(12, 13):
        if main.cell(i,j).value != None:
            data.cell(data.max_row+1, column=j-11).value = main.cell(row=i, column=j).value

Comment: Please share **all** relevant code and data. See: [mcve]. As an aside, you should use `is` to check if a variable is `None`, rather than `==`.

Comment: Good job, Kate! Why not put your solution down below as 'Your Answer'. You can then mark it as the right solution so future stackoverflow users who have the same question can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code we got working (see the comments for the back and forth):

```
import os
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/path/.xlsx')
main = wb['Sheet1']
wb.create_sheet(title='Formatted Data')
data = wb['Formatted Data']

for i in range(2, 50):
    for j in range(12, 13):
        if main.cell(i,j).value != None:
            data.cell(data.max_row+1, column=j-11).value = main.cell(row=i, column=j).value
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever possible you should avoid using your own counters and let openpyxl do the work for you. For a new worksheet this is pretty easy.

```
empty_row = [None] * 11
for row in main.iter_rows(min_col=12, max_col=2, min_row=2, values_only=True):
    if row[0] != None:
         data.append(empty_row + row]
```